# Python Selenium custom headers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use custom headers, python, selenium in order to avoid detection of the scrapper.

In the past I used the code something like that:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

custom_headers = {
    'authority': 'www.google.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url, headers = custom_headers)
```

However, as of now it results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\python\scrapper\bot\bot_fin\int - Copy.py", line 23, in <module>
    driver.get(url, headers = custom_headers)
TypeError: WebDriver.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

What should I change to make it work?